# Why mutliple transport ICE candidate allocated even when sdp using `a=group:BUNDLE 0 1` in chrome?

Tags: webrtc, sdp

Chrome version: `113.0.5672.129`。

Offer sdp:

```
v=0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
...
m=video
a=mid:0
...
m=application 
a=mid:1
```

But I found the ice candidates collected locally are splitted into two groups, one for mid-0, the other for mid-1:

```
sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:2558938800 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.2.200 54078 typ host generation 0 ufrag DncU network-id 1
sdpMid: 1, sdpMLineIndex: 1, candidate: candidate:2558938800 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.2.200 54079 typ host generation 0 ufrag DncU network-id 1
sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1250609983 1 udp 1686052607 115.89.7.51 60609 typ srflx raddr 192.168.2.200 rport 54078 generation 0 ufrag DncU network-id 1
sdpMid: 1, sdpMLineIndex: 1, candidate: candidate:1250609983 1 udp 1686052607 115.89.7.51 43434 typ srflx raddr 192.168.2.200 rport 54079 generation 0 ufrag DncU network-id 1
```

It this a bug for chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you set the [`bundlePolicy`](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcbundlepolicy-enum) to `max-bundle` that is the behavior required by the specification.

Comment: thank you. I known if I set bundlePolicy to max-bundle, just candidate with mid=0 will be discovered. What I don't understand here is why the Candidate with mid=1 is still used even though the group bundle is clearly specified in the sdp? The other side sees the group bundle, doesn't it think there is only one transport?

Comment: BUNDLE is negotiated. Before you receive the answer, unless you configure max-bundle, it must be assumed that the other side does not support it, hence the implementation must gather candidates for the different mids.